# Django Rest Framework - Serializer validation doesn't work

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have simple serializer in my `serializers.py` and I want to validate one of the fields using `validate(self, data)` but it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
class DataUpdateSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    def validate(self, data):
        if data['username'] != 'test':
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Wrong username')
        return data
```

I don't know if it will help but here are my `views.py`

```
class DataUpdateAPI(views.APIView):
    serializer_class = DataUpdateSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('pass')

        return Response("Just test response")
```

I don't know what's wrong with this code. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`APIView` is a low-level view class that doesn't use `serializer_class` attribute. If you want to use it, you have to instantiate and invoke the serializer yourself:

```
import rest_framework

class DataUpdateAPI(views.APIView):

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = DataUpdateSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            # do smth with serializer.data, it's valid now
            return Response("Just test response")
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=rest_framework.status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

If you want more high-level usage, the invocation of `serializer_class` is implemented in [`GenericAPIView`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#genericapiview) and subclasses. For example, [`CreateAPIView`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#createapiview) already implements the `post` method with deserializing and validation, so you don't have to reinvent the wheel:

```
class DataUpdateSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    def validate(self, data):
        if data['username'] != 'test':
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Wrong username')
        return data

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print('my data is already validated here', validated_data)


class DataUpdateAPI(rest_framework.generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = DataUpdateSerializer
```

Comment: Thanks! Great explained!

Answer (score 2):

At first, you should not use request.POST insted of it you should use, request.data(it is more usefull)

Also you should not use views.APIView, you should use generics.UpdateAPIView (because you are update fields)

But I do not undestend what you want to do? DO you want to update test users password?

You should use serializer in your post function

```
def post(self, request)
    data = request.data
    serializer = DataUpdateSerializer(data=data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
       return Response("all right")
    return Response(data=serializer.errors)
```